# /dev/sda1 or /dev/sdb1 i should write my iso? If i do wrong what will happen, can i reverse back?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, fedora, fedora-15

I did a mistake and realized i would have choosen /dev/sdb1 instead of /dev/sda1. My own system i did something. But how can i reverse back? (i am sure if i reboot my system i wont be able to login back).

This is what i did, was trying to make a usb bootable, but i put it to sda1:

```
# livecd-iso-to-disk ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sda1
Verifying image...

The media check is complete, the result is: NA.

No checksum information available, unable to verify media.
Are you SURE you want to continue?
Press Enter to continue or ctrl-c to abort

/dev/sda1 is mounted, please unmount for safety
Cleaning up to exit...

# umount /dev/sda1
# livecd-iso-to-disk ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sda1
Verifying image...

The media check is complete, the result is: NA.

No checksum information available, unable to verify media.
Are you SURE you want to continue?
Press Enter to continue or ctrl-c to abort

ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso uses initrd.img w/o install.img
Copying DVD image to target device.
Updating boot config file
Installing boot loader
/media/tgttmp.WBEQ4L/syslinux is device /dev/sda1
Target device is now set up with a Live image!
```

Follow up:

When /boot is empty i am lost, i can not reverse. I just verified with my other CentOS box which contain lot of stuffs:

```
$ ls
config-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64  initramfs-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64.img  symvers-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.gz       vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
config-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64       initramfs-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.img       System.map-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64
efi                               lost+found                               System.map-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
grub                              symvers-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64.gz     vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64
```

Where as my current system after the mistake is:

```
$ ls
bin   cgroup  etc         home  lost+found  misc  opt   root  sbin     srv  tmp        usr
boot  dev     folders.db  lib   media       mnt   proc  run   selinux  sys  trace.txt  var

$ ll /boot
total 0
```

Best thing to do is now backup and install Fedora 16. Never do the same mistake next time with sda1 and sdb1

Comment: what was on sda1? Your current OS?

Comment: @KovBal: Yes that is my laptop disk.

Comment: Which filesystem was sda1?

Comment: How could you unmounted it with `umount /dev/sda1` ? There must be open files on it...

Comment: @Darokthar: /dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)

Comment: @KovBal: /boot is empty now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `/dev/sda1` is your boot partition, all you have to do is reinstall the boot loader, which was most likely GRUB in Fedora 15.

You can find numerous guides, like [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Installation_Guide/s1-grub-installing.html).
However, if `livecd-iso-to-disk` did not removed your files in the partition, than all you have to do is:

1. issue `grub` as root, it gives you the grub prompt
2. `root (hd0, 1)`
3. `setup (hd0)`

Comment: If /boot is empty, than it takes a little more than that, like reinstalling the kernel.

Comment: As of this moment, after using livecd-iso-to-disk, my /boot is completely empty.

Comment: Thanks, i will backup now all, and install Fedora 16. I lose my Fedora 15, for this mistake.